# Insistence of third party warning in Pokémon go

Tags: pokemon-go

So look.. I was using iv go app linked to my account till I got the third party warning message from Pokémon go today. I immediately deleted the app and changed my Google account password. But the message still keeps appearing.. What should I do? Am i in trouble? Note that I'm not a spoofer and my only action that violated the PoGo terms and conditions was my use of the iv app[image]

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling the app? if that doesnt work idk. maybe try submitting a ticket to their support

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do?

Sounds like they've set a flag on your account for using third party software.  I doubt there's anything you can do on your end to remove that flag, short of creating a new account, of course.

The best you can do is discontinue use of any third party software and hope it goes away.  Try deleting and reinstalling the Pokemon Go app, as Dragonrage suggests.  (Unless that's what you meant by "deleted the app.")  Also remove any other software related to this IV Go app from your device.

If you haven't already, try doing a full shutdown and reboot on your device.  (I'm not sure that would help at all, but it's Step 1 in just about every tech-related issue.)

Assuming none of that works, try connecting from a different Access Point.  Deny data access to PoGo and use WiFi on a network you haven't accessed the game on before.  Maybe they've blacklisted your known IP(s)?

Beyond all this, the only thing I can think of is to contact customer support and ask them how to get rid of the notice.  (Don't admit anything over the phone, just say it appeared one day and you're trying to get rid of it, then do whatever they say.)

> Am i in trouble?

As far as legal consequences go, I doubt you're facing anything more severe than being banned from the game - and that doesn't appear to have happened *yet,* so as long as you play it straight from here on out, you should be okay.

Comment: I would add to this the suggestion of checking the apps connected to their Google Account. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521